# How to handle Gitlab-API errors returned as array with same message?

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm creating a project where I communicate with the Gitlab API and I'm currently thinging on how to handle errors. Typically, when error occurs you would show any notification in the frontend (e.g. https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html).
But according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#data-validation-and-error-reporting I'm sometimes getting back arrays of errors. So I thought, "ok, simply show multipl error notifications", but now I tried to create a project with the same name twice and getting back the following errors:

```json
"message": {
  "project_namespace.name": [
    "has already been taken"
  ],
  "name": [
    "has already been taken"
  ],
  "path": [
    "has already been taken"
  ]
}
```

By the way, I only specify the project `name` and `namespace_id`. So `path` and `name` are the same.

In this case I would show 3 error messages with "has already been taken" which would be a bit confusing in the frontend, seeing the same error 3 times and even without the project name (`has already been taken` instead of `<Projectname> has already been taken`). So I wonder how other ppl are handling this behavior? Any idea how to handle this? Would you filter it so that it shows `has already been taken` only once?